# "List does not exist" error for site cache settings

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, error

I'm trying to edit the site cache settings of a publishing site.

When I navigate to `_layouts/sitecachesettings.aspx`, I get the following error:

> List does not exist
>
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

Any idea as to what might be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Finnaly found a solution thanks to this post!

I just have deactivated "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature and activated it again. All works now!

Before to do this, try on your testing environment to be sure it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. That page accesses a hidden list called "Cache Profiles" which may have been deleted somehow or there may be something wrong with it. Can you browse the site collection in VS.NET 2010 Server explorer and see if this list is present?

Comment: Hi Ashish -- I browsed the site collection with SPM 2007 (I have VS 2008 and couldn't find Server Explorer) and the Cache Profiles list does exist, however I noticed that the four usual list items ("Disabled", "Extranet", "Intranet", "Public Internet") are all in the list twice.  So it does look like there's something wrong with the list...

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but sorry, I could not reproduce the problem with Sharepoint 2010 that I have. My best guess is that someone deactivated and activated the Publishing Infrastructure feature at the site collection level. The problem might have been resolved in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Sorry, but the error always exists in SP 2010. I have this one and do not know how to fix this